# How to retrieve data from firebase and then update the data using Swift5

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

After the current user watches the video ad, it will retrieve their point (which is stored in the firebase) and add 1 to their point. Then, it will update the document and also display the number of points the user has. It seems like everything is okay, except, I can't do `scoreText.text = point`

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
   let dBRef = Database.database().reference()
    dBRef.child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        var point = dict["point"] as? Int

        point!+=1
        dBRef.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).setValue(["point": point])

        scoreText.text = point

    })
```

[image: image of my firebase database]

How would I display the user's points?

[UPDATED CODE]
Changed code to access Cloud Firestore, not Realtime Database

```
 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
    //[START update_document-increment
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(UserID!)
    // Atomically increment the population of the city by 1.
    docRef.updateData([
        "points": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
    ])
    //[END update_document-increment]


    //insert point value here
    scoreText.text =
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete/standalone reproduction of the problem you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I highly recommend studying that link, as following the advice in there will increase the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I hope I've made it much more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're showing accesses the Realtime Database, while he screenshot shows Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the API for one doesn't apply to the other.

To fix the problem, you will have to either use the Cloud Firestore API, or enter the data into the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have updated my code and have updated my post. Now, everytime the user watches the ad, it will increment the "point" by 1 on my database. However, how do I retrieve that value so that I can show it on my UILabel `scoreText.text=`?

Comment: I have created a new question for the new problem, like you have mentioned.